# Brightness keys not working on 3.14+ kernel

Tags: linux, keyboard, laptop

I have a dual-boot installation: OpenSuSE 13.2 & Linux Mint 17.1 on Asus k55vd, both 64-bit. I am running a 3.14 kernel on Linux Mint
and 3.16 on OpenSuSE.

I had encountered  that kernels above 3.14  have problem with function keys. The brightness + and - function keys do not work The rest all are working (sound +/-, sleep, mute, lock touch).

I  had  this problem  on   all distributions I  tried (Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenSuSE) having kernel 3.14 or above.

So how to resolve this? Do not recommend downgrade my kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Install xbacklight. Find the code for the brightness keys ctrl-v then press the key combination. The code will echo to terminal.

```
bind '"brightness_up_code":"xbacklight -inc 10"'
bind '"brightness_down_code":"xbacklight -dec 10"'
```

Should do it.